# Dynamic Table and Column Names In hive platform

Tags: hive

```
    CREATE TABLE concat(cast(weekday(getdate()) as STRING),'_',cast(datepart(getdate(),'dd') as STRING ))(
            id STRING,
            date_time DATETIME,
            cnt int         
)
```

basically I want to create table and assign its name using query "`concat(cast(weekday(getdate()) as STRING),'_',cast(datepart(getdate(),'dd') as STRING ))`", but unable to do this it throws error.

Comment: don't post your code in comments

Comment: So if I have understood your requirement right, you want your _Tablename_ to be derived from the query. That's not possible using the _Hive Shell_. You can make use of Shell Scripting and pass in the Tablename as variable using `hiveconf`.

Comment: @Joby i've tried that too but didn't work

Comment: @AmritRaj could you please share the `code` that you tried running via Shell Scripting ?